# Making a matrix block diagonal by linear transformation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, direct-sum

I am trying to make a block diagonal matrix from a given matrix by multiplying the given matrix to some other matrices.
Say $A$ is an $N \times N$ matrix, I want to make an $A^\prime$ matrix with size $kN  \times kN$ such that $A^\prime$ has $A$ as its diagonal element $k$ times. In fact $A^\prime$ is the direct sum of A as $A^\prime = \bigoplus_{i =1}^{k} A$.

What I am looking for is what the elements of $B$ and $C$ should be to have
$$ BAC =A^\prime . $$

**Use case:** Using $A^\prime$ in a linear optimization problem if $A$ can be transformed to $A^\prime$ linearly.

Comment: Are you asking for the size of $B$ and $C$ or what the elements should be?

Comment: @m1cky22  What the elements should be.

Comment: What have you come up with so far? Have you successfully tried $1\times1,2\times2,3\times3$, or any other matrices?

Comment: @m1cky22 Well, I know that the size of B and C must be $kN \times N$ and $N \times kN$, respectively, and they must be made up with integer elements, probably with $I(N)$, but could not find the answer.

Comment: So have you tried any $2\times2$ matrices for $A$ and try to come up with $B$ and $C$?

Comment: shouldn't the dimensions of A′ be (kN)×(kN) instead? tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, with 2x2 I could not find B and C. But I need the general approach as the size of my problem is much bigger.

Comment: @Med you are right. And the size of B and C must be like what I commented above. (I modified that, what I commented first was not correct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Med points out, it is generally not possible to do what you want with only one "matrix sandwich". However, it is possible with $k$ "matrix sandwiches" as follows:

$$A' = \begin{bmatrix}
I \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}A
\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 & \dots & 0
\end{bmatrix}
+ 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ I \\ \vdots \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}A
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & I & \dots & 0
\end{bmatrix}
+ \dots +
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ I
\end{bmatrix}A
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & \dots & I
\end{bmatrix},$$
where $0$ and $I$ are the zero matrix and identity matrix of the appropriate sizes, respectively. More succicintly,
$$A' = B_1 A B_1^T + B_2 A B_2^T + \dots + B_k A B_k^T,$$
where the matrices $B_i$ are the tall rectangular matrices with zero and identity blocks as shown above.

Also note that the map from $A$ to $A'$ is linear, and the [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) of the map can be expressed using the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) as follows:
$$\text{vec}(A') = \left(B_1 \otimes B_1 + B_2 \otimes B_2 + \dots + B_k \otimes B_k\right)\text{vec}(A).$$

Comment: Many thanks Nick. Actually my goal was to make $A^\prime$ by a linear combination and use it in a linear optimization problem!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to find matrices $B$ and $C$ to get what you want. To give a simple example, the matrix A' is a general form of the identity matrix "I".

$B_{kN×N}.1_{N×N}.C_{N×kN}=I_{kN×kN}$

Having a column vector "B" and a row vector "C", you cannot get the identity matrix. Because the identity matrix is a full rank matrix and multiplication of matrices, that at least one of them is not full rank, would give a singular matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot with this clear answer. I tried with $A$ as some $2\times2$ matrix and it became complicated for me to find the answer. With $A$ as a $1\times1$ matrix it is very straightforward to see that there are no $B$ and $C$ to satisfy the equation.

Comment: Glad you find it helpful